# blank xml with root only

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi I am trying to error handle blank xml files in vb.net the original xml looks like this.

```
<settings>
   <connection = "aaaa" user = "bbbb" perm = "bgshs"
</settings>
```

the problem is that I am trying to check if xml has root only ie blank and then up it sent it somewhere else. eg

```
<settings>
</settings>
```

Comment: I think your question is missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = "<settings></settings>"
        Dim element As XElement = XElement.Parse(Input)
        If Not element.HasElements Then

            Console.WriteLine("Has no elements")

            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
​
```